# how to get all objects between two column from a javascript array

Tags: javascript, node.js, sorting, multidimensional-array, iteration

I have this sample array.

```
     [
        {
            __EMPTY: 'POS:',
            __EMPTY_1: 'LOUN - LOUNGE',
        },
        {
            __EMPTY: 44946,
            __EMPTY_1: 'LB015260',
            __EMPTY_2: '15:04',
            __EMPTY_3: 'L-15',
            __EMPTY_4: 1402,

            __EMPTY_5: 'AKASH',
            __EMPTY_6: 66.78,
            __EMPTY_7: 0,
        },
        {
            __EMPTY: 44946,
            __EMPTY_1: 'LB015260',
            __EMPTY_2: '15:04',
            __EMPTY_3: 'L-15',
            __EMPTY_4: 1402,

            __EMPTY_5: 'AKASH',
            __EMPTY_6: 66.78,
            __EMPTY_7: 0,
        },
        {
            __EMPTY: 44946,
            __EMPTY_1: 'LB015260',
            __EMPTY_2: '15:04',
            __EMPTY_3: 'L-15',
            __EMPTY_4: 1402,

            __EMPTY_5: 'AKASH',
            __EMPTY_6: 66.78,
            __EMPTY_7: 0,
        },
        {
            __EMPTY: 'POS:',
            __EMPTY_1: 'PARTY - PARTY',
        },
        {
            __EMPTY: 44946,
            __EMPTY_1: 'LB015260',
            __EMPTY_2: '15:04',
            __EMPTY_3: 'L-15',
            __EMPTY_4: 1402,

            __EMPTY_5: 'AKASH',
            __EMPTY_6: 66.78,
            __EMPTY_7: 0,
        },
        {
            __EMPTY: 44946,
            __EMPTY_1: 'LB015260',
            __EMPTY_2: '15:04',
            __EMPTY_3: 'L-15',
            __EMPTY_4: 1402,

            __EMPTY_5: 'AKASH',
            __EMPTY_6: 66.78,
            __EMPTY_7: 0,
        },
        {
            __EMPTY: 'POS:',
            __EMPTY_1: 'TERRACE - TERRACE',
        },
        {
            __EMPTY: 44946,
            __EMPTY_1: 'LB015260',
            __EMPTY_2: '15:04',
            __EMPTY_3: 'L-15',
            __EMPTY_4: 1402,

            __EMPTY_5: 'AKASH',
            __EMPTY_6: 66.78,
            __EMPTY_7: 0,
        },
    ];
```

How can I get array like below

```
[{
  'LOUN - LOUNGE':
    [{
      __EMPTY: 44946,
      __EMPTY_1: 'LB015260',
      __EMPTY_2: '15:04',
      __EMPTY_3: 'L-15',
      __EMPTY_4: 1402,

      __EMPTY_5: 'AKASH',
      __EMPTY_6: 66.78,
      __EMPTY_7: 0,
    },
    {
      __EMPTY: 44946,
      __EMPTY_1: 'LB015260',
      __EMPTY_2: '15:04',
      __EMPTY_3: 'L-15',
      __EMPTY_4: 1402,

      __EMPTY_5: 'AKASH',
      __EMPTY_6: 66.78,
      __EMPTY_7: 0,
    },
    {
      __EMPTY: 44946,
      __EMPTY_1: 'LB015260',
      __EMPTY_2: '15:04',
      __EMPTY_3: 'L-15',
      __EMPTY_4: 1402,

      __EMPTY_5: 'AKASH',
      __EMPTY_6: 66.78,
      __EMPTY_7: 0,
    }],
        
  'PARTY - PARTY':
        
    [{
      __EMPTY: 44946,
      __EMPTY_1: 'LB015260',
      __EMPTY_2: '15:04',
      __EMPTY_3: 'L-15',
      __EMPTY_4: 1402,

      __EMPTY_5: 'AKASH',
      __EMPTY_6: 66.78,
      __EMPTY_7: 0,
    },
    {
      __EMPTY: 44946,
      __EMPTY_1: 'LB015260',
      __EMPTY_2: '15:04',
      __EMPTY_3: 'L-15',
      __EMPTY_4: 1402,

      __EMPTY_5: 'AKASH',
      __EMPTY_6: 66.78,
      __EMPTY_7: 0,
    }],
  'TERRACE - TERRACE':
    [{
      __EMPTY: 44946,
      __EMPTY_1: 'LB015260',
      __EMPTY_2: '15:04',
      __EMPTY_3: 'L-15',
      __EMPTY_4: 1402,
      __EMPTY_5: 'AKASH',
      __EMPTY_6: 66.78,
      __EMPTY_7: 0,
    }]
}]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `reduce` to keep track of the current key and collect the objects in the corresponding subarray:

```js
const data = [{__EMPTY: 'POS:',__EMPTY_1: 'LOUN - LOUNGE',},{__EMPTY: 44946,__EMPTY_1: 'LB015260',__EMPTY_2: '15:04',__EMPTY_3: 'L-15',__EMPTY_4: 1402,__EMPTY_5: 'AKASH',__EMPTY_6: 66.78,__EMPTY_7: 0,},{__EMPTY: 44946,__EMPTY_1: 'LB015260',__EMPTY_2: '15:04',__EMPTY_3: 'L-15',__EMPTY_4: 1402,__EMPTY_5: 'AKASH',__EMPTY_6: 66.78,__EMPTY_7: 0,},{__EMPTY: 44946,__EMPTY_1: 'LB015260',__EMPTY_2: '15:04',__EMPTY_3: 'L-15',__EMPTY_4: 1402,__EMPTY_5: 'AKASH',__EMPTY_6: 66.78,__EMPTY_7: 0,},{__EMPTY: 'POS:',__EMPTY_1: 'PARTY - PARTY',},{__EMPTY: 44946,__EMPTY_1: 'LB015260',__EMPTY_2: '15:04',__EMPTY_3: 'L-15',__EMPTY_4: 1402,__EMPTY_5: 'AKASH',__EMPTY_6: 66.78,__EMPTY_7: 0,},{__EMPTY: 44946,__EMPTY_1: 'LB015260',__EMPTY_2: '15:04',__EMPTY_3: 'L-15',__EMPTY_4: 1402,__EMPTY_5: 'AKASH',__EMPTY_6: 66.78,__EMPTY_7: 0,},{__EMPTY: 'POS:',__EMPTY_1: 'TERRACE - TERRACE',},{__EMPTY: 44946,__EMPTY_1: 'LB015260',__EMPTY_2: '15:04',__EMPTY_3: 'L-15',__EMPTY_4: 1402,__EMPTY_5: 'AKASH',__EMPTY_6: 66.78,__EMPTY_7: 0,},];
    
const [result] = data.reduce(([acc, key], obj) =>
    obj.__EMPTY === "POS:" 
             ? [acc, obj.__EMPTY_1]
             : [((acc[key] ??= []).push(obj), acc), key]
, [{}]);

console.log(result);
```